# Constant propagation library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, f#, static-analysis

Whether any open source .NET (C#/F#) library for abstract static analysis exists? Currently I'm interested in constant propagation algorithm.

It should be abstract (language independed) and open source because I want to use it as base for custom algorithm implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: You insist on open source?

Answer (score 2):

The library [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) is almost what you want. It is open-source, language abstracted and as a bonus it is super polished, fast and stable.

But it is not exactly what you want because Cecil doesn't analyze C#, VB.NET or F# source code, but it analyzes assemblies files (dll and exe) and IL code contained in assemblies. For many static analysis areas it'd be enough, but for constant propagation (I guess you mean literal constant like `const string STR = "MyString";` or `const int INT = 12345;`) there is a loss of information at compile time since the constant value is hardcoded in place of the constant usage. Cecil is also not suited for [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) analysis.

You can also look at [Microsoft Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn). Contrary to Cecil, Roslyn parses C# and VB.NET source code, is very well suited for [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) analysis, but it is not open source, doesn't support F#, and is certainly subject to change until it will become RTM, I'd say next year with Visual Studio 2014, (but this is just my guess).

Comment: Thank you for answer. All libraries are very interesting. But I find more high-level abstraction.

Comment: What you mean by "I find more high-level abstraction"?

Comment: Sorry. Part of answer was lost. I means that I try to found somethink like pranlib for ocaml (https://code.google.com/p/ocaml-pranlib/): the set of analysis implemented for abstract, language-independed data structures.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the Common Compiler Infrastructure: Code and AST components [project](http://cciast.codeplex.com/). It provides an object model for doing static analysis on .NET assemblies in a language-independent form.

**Update**

The CCI projects are designed more as libraries for compiler and tooling authors rather than out-of-the-box usage.

Perhaps you are looking for something more like [Mono.Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme) which is an open source static analysis engine, similar to FxCop. It is maintained as part of the [Mono-Tools](https://github.com/mono/mono-tools) collection of projects.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good idea. Are any analysis implemented or planned?

Comment: @gsv I don't think there are although I would ask the project maintainer on plans for the project. Actually I don't think the CCI project is good fit for you, I think you are looking for something like the Mono.Gendarme project. See my edit.